# Sorting XSL Templates by similar tags

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to output a travel itinerary read from a database into a PDF.
Retreiving etc etc is all good, however i would like to order the itinerary by date.

Currently the xml structure is as follows

```
    <flights>
      <flDate>13OCT</flDate>
      <flFrom>Glasgow International </flFrom>
      <flTo>Philadelphia, PA - International </flTo>
      <flNumber>US769</flNumber>
      <depTime>1020</depTime>
      <arrTime>1300</arrTime>
    </flights>
    <flights>
      <flDate>22OCT</flDate>
      <flFrom>Philadelphia, PA - International </flFrom>
      <flTo>Glasgow International </flTo>
      <flNumber>US768</flNumber>
      <depTime>1855</depTime>
      <arrTime>1830</arrTime>
    </flights>
    <accommodation>
      <accDate>14OCT</accDate>
      <accName>Hotel Los Jameos</accName>
      <duration>10</duration>
      <roomType>Type B Rooms</roomType>
      <boardBasis>H/B</boardBasis>
    </accommodation>
```

Output at the moment is

```
  13OCT Glasgow to Phili
  ..........
  22OCT Phili to Glasgow
  ..........
  14OCT Hotel Los Jameos
  ..........
```

Obviously this isn't ideal and leads to confusion. Ideally i would like the accommodation (and any other itinerary items) to be in the correct date order.

How would I go about that? I'm thinking it maybe a change instructure to the database or the XML.

Current XSL below.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="iOverview/itinLeg">
      <xsl:sort select="flights/flDate" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="accommodation/accDate" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="flights[count(.|key('fDate', flDate)[1])=1]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="accommodation"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:template match="flights">
      <fo:block margin-top="2mm">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('fDate', flDate)">
          <xsl:sort select="flDate"/>
          <fo:block>
              <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="flDate"/></fo:inline>
              <fo:inline padding-left="4mm"><xsl:value-of select="flFrom"/></fo:inline>
              <fo:inline padding-left="1mm">to</fo:inline>
              <fo:inline padding-left="2mm"><xsl:value-of select="flTo"/></fo:inline>
          </fo:block>
          .......
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

Accommodation xsl similar just different elements names really.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What does exactly the desired output look like?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all dates have the same year component? If not, the data in the XML document is insufficient for correct sorting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MCVE is not so complete, so I added an `<xsl:key name="fDate" match="flights" use="flDate" />` to complete it. I also inferred the surrounding tags from your XSLT. Sorting the output can be done be merging the search expression to `flDate | accDate`. I omitted the XSL:FO blocks for clarity, you would probably like to readd them to your final solution.

The resulting XSLT-1.0 stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="fDate" match="flights" use="flDate" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="iOverview/itinLeg">
      <xsl:for-each select="flights | accommodation">
        <xsl:sort select="flDate | accDate" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="flights[count(.|key('fDate', flDate)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('fDate', flDate)">
      <xsl:value-of select="flDate"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(flFrom)"/> to <xsl:value-of select="flTo"/><xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="flights[count(.|key('fDate', flDate)[1]) > 1]" />      <!-- filter out any dates with more than one matches -->

  <xsl:template match="accommodation">
    <xsl:value-of select="accDate"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="accName"/><xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input data the **output** is as follows:

```
22OCT Philadelphia, PA - International to Glasgow International 
14OCT Hotel Los Jameos
13OCT Glasgow International to Philadelphia, PA - International
```

If you consider the order of times to be wrong, just replace "descending" with "ascending" in the `".

Comment: Thank you, this works fine with current demo data. Will need to test dec into jan etc (probably change datatype etc..). I didn't know about using | as an or test.The key variable had already been defined just didn't want to paste everything in and spend ages formating. Help greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could have been of some help. My test-data-set was greater than your demo data, it sorted everything by "dateTime" and it worked well. If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to ask. If this answer suffices, don't hesitate to accept it, either ;-)

Comment: Don't want to sound ungrateful etc.. Discovered a slight issue in that it displays the accommodation itinerary layout or cruise itinerary when they aren't part of the itinerary (i.e. The itinerary can be made up of flights only, flight and crusing, flight and accommodation etc etc). They appear as self closing tags in the xml so not sure if that is causing it. Tried apply the filters and doing if tests but no joy. can you point me the correct direction. Many Thanks

Comment: @IanC: Well...without the surrounding data (structure/XML) I cannot possibly know how to process it. I don't know neither the input nor the output... I already had to infer some missing parts of your current XSLT to approach the current answer. Actually, after this last comment, we don't have a working MCVE anymore with which I could test if my answer fulfills your requirements. So I could only shoot into the blue which would be kind of pointless.

Comment: @IanC ". Will need to test dec into jan etc (probably change datatype etc..)" I am not sure you understand that the sort method used here will sort the events within each month - and then each month in **alphabetical**, instead of calendrical order. Also, the sort within the month depends on the format being DDMMM (i.e. zero-padding for single-digit days).

Answer (score 1):

First, you're going to have trouble sorting with this date format. Change it to something sane like 2016-10-05, and then you can sort dates as if they were strings.

Your next challenge is that the expression to compute the sort key for flights is different from that for hotels, but you want to sort into a single sequence. But that is easily overcome; just use a union expression in the `xsl:sort/@select`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
  <xsl:sort select="self::flights/flDate | self::accomodation/accDate"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us reduce the example to the minimum necessary to deal with the problem of sorting nodes by date in the given DMMM format (at least that's how it seems).

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<itinerary>
    <flight>
        <flDate>25OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <flDate>13NOV</flDate>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <flDate>9SEP</flDate>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <flDate>13OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <flDate>28AUG</flDate>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <flDate>5OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
</itinerary>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="months" select="'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'" />

<xsl:template match="/itinerary">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="flight">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($months, translate(flDate, '0123456789', '')))" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="translate(flDate, 'ABCDEFGJLMNOPRSTUVY', '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<itinerary>
  <flight>
        <flDate>28AUG</flDate>
    </flight>
  <flight>
        <flDate>9SEP</flDate>
    </flight>
  <flight>
        <flDate>5OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
  <flight>
        <flDate>13OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
  <flight>
        <flDate>25OCT</flDate>
    </flight>
  <flight>
        <flDate>13NOV</flDate>
    </flight>
</itinerary>
```

**Note**: This will produce incorrect results when your itinerary spans a year boundary: events in January of the next year will be sorted *before* events in December of this year.